# Wraparound Banner with CSS

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, banner

I'm currently trying to use this CSS to set up a wraparound banner type deal on a website theme I'm working on:

http://asgeirhoem.no/ex/css-wraparound-ribbon/

I've pretty much copied verbatim what's shown on the mentioned site:

(CSS)

```
header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #bb0000;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 black;
}

header:before,
header:after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 10px solid #660000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
}

header:before {
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

header:after {
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

(HTML)

```
<body>

  <div class="page-container">
    <header>
      <img src="logo1.png" />
    </header>
  </div>

</body>
```

But it's not working as expected.  This is what I'm getting when I look at the page in a browser:

[image]

As you can see, the "wraparound" sections exist, but are not positioned correctly, and I'm not sure why that is.  Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the `left` and `right` property:

```
header:before {
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    left: 0;
}
header:after {
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    right: 0;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jDZC/1/)

Comment: Just what I said 2 seconds after you. :)

Comment: @ShengSlogar You're a real sportsman by deleting your answer :)

Comment: Oh wow, I overlooked that.   This is what I get for writing code while half asleep.   Much appreciated.  I figured it was something I just wasn't seeing.

Comment: @nkmol thanks! It was probably more than a few seconds, but it said 1 minute ago and 58 seconds ago. Of course, it's rounded. :) The problem probably is that StackOverflow dosen't seem to check for updates on mobile.